# Gatsby - Graphql error "not defined by type MarkdownRemarkFieldsFilterInput" for gatsby-plugin-categories

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

### Expected Result

I should be able to see a category page. I did exactly what the documentation said at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-categories

### Actual Result

Geting a build error

```
error GraphQL Error Field "category" is not defined by type MarkdownRemarkFieldsFilterInput.
```

---

### Code

#### src/templates/category.js

```
import React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import { graphql } from "gatsby";
import Layout from "../layout";
import PostListing from "../components/PostListing";

export default class CategoryTemplate extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { pageContext, data } = this.props;
    const { category } = pageContext;
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div className="category-container">
          <Helmet title={`Posts in category "${category}"`} />
          <PostListing postEdges={data.allMarkdownRemark.edges} />
        </div>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query CategoryPage($category: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 1000
      filter: { fields: { category: { eq: $category } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
            category
          }
          excerpt
          timeToRead
          frontmatter {
            title
            tags
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

#### gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `VLLG`,
    description: `Village | California Campsites.`,
    author: `Juan Gallardo`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/pages/`,
      },
    },
    {
    resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
    options: {
      // CommonMark mode (default: true)
      commonmark: true,
      // Footnotes mode (default: true)
      footnotes: true,
      // Pedantic mode (default: true)
      pedantic: true,
      // GitHub Flavored Markdown mode (default: true)
      gfm: true,
      // Plugins configs
      plugins: [],
    },
  },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `VLLG`,
        short_name: `vllg`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    // this (optional) plugin enables Progressive Web App + Offline functionality
    // To learn more, visit: https://gatsby.dev/offline
    // 'gatsby-plugin-offline',
  ],
}
```

#### How I added a category to a post (in a .md file)

```
category: 'lol'
```

#### Structure for blog posts

[image]

#### Results from Graphql query

[image]

Comment: you have not added `gatsby-plugin-categories` to gatsby config

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings wow can't believe i missed that. now getting other errors but will look those up `ReferenceError: path is not defined`.